# How to connect a site that runs in a container?

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile, ubuntu-16.04, nvidia-digits

I'm running a DIGITS in a container and I'm starting that container with `-p 5001` parameter. How can I connect that DIGITS site using my host pc? Here is how my container looks like when i run DIGITS app.

[image: Image:]

Comment: Run `docker inspect 2f1a6(...)` to check if the container has any ports exposed. If not, you will have to recreate the container with exposed ports.

Comment: Thanks so much! It gave me whole network properties and I saw that there is an IP address. Then in my real browser, I entered [Container IP address]:5001 and DIGITS showed up.  @Nebril

Comment: Ok, will add this as an answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `docker inspect <container ID>` (your container id starts with `2f1a6`, which will provide you with network configuration of your container.

You can then try to connect to `container_ip:5001` to access your service.